# How do you concatenate multiple videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a directory with multiple MP4 files, how do I concatenate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, generate a list of videos you want to merge, e.g. using this script to create a file with all the mp4 files in the current directory (in alphabetical order):

```sh
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.mp4 > mylist.txt
```

Then concatenate them using:

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

And to remove the text file:

```sh
rm mylist.txt
```

---

As a one-liner, which converts all MP4 files in the current directory into one, concatenated MP4 called output.mp4:

```sh
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.mp4 > mylist.txt ; ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4 ; rm mylist.txt
```

Comment: Recommend citing your source so others can read more. [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).